# Guibuilder right menu option not available

Tags: codenameone

Using Eclipse Photon and the newest version of the Codename One plugin, I have an issue where I create a new project and then create a GuiBuilder form inside that project, but when right clicking on that form I do not see any of the Codename One specific options I should be seeing, like the Guibuilder option.  So I can't open the form in the Guibuilder.

This is happening in a 36 seat computer lab, but not on my office machine.  Any ideas what might be going wrong in the lab?

Comment: Is it possible that the path to the project has spaces or problematic characters within it? We translate file names to URL's and have some encoding issues when going back and forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else has this same issue, as Shai suggested, it had to do with where the Eclipse workspace was located.  In my case I had it on the lab desktop.

There were spaces in the path, but even removing those did not solve the problem if the workspace was on the desktop.  When I moved the workspace to the user folder, all started working as I would expect it to work.

There might be an issue with the length of the workspace path, along with special characters.  Regardless, relocating the workspace to c:\users\win10\workspace solved the issue for the lab computers.